# Libgdx framebuffer blending not working

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, framebuffer

I am attempting to make dynamic 2D shadows in my game.

I'm successfully able to render the shadows to a frame buffer. (grey and white squares designate transparency)

[image]

Then for debug purposes, I render the contents of the frame buffer on top of another frame buffer which is cleared white every frame, and then render this frame on my game. This works just fine... as long as I render the shadows with 100% opaqueness:

[image]

But if I do this before drawing the shadows on the second framebuffer,

```
spriteBatch.setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
```

The transparent shadows tear through the framebuffer and you can see the game world underneath.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public class Light
{
    FrameBuffer shadowbuffer; // for rendering shadows
    FrameBuffer buffer; // for debug
    OrthographicCamera cam;

    public Light(Images images)
    {
        shadowbuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

        buffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);     

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight());
        cam.setToOrtho(true);
        cam.update();
    }

    public Texture render(SpriteBatch batch, GameWorld world)
    {
        batch.end();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        shadowbuffer.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
        batch.begin();

        // ... render shadows here ...

        batch.end();
        shadowbuffer.end();

        buffer.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        batch.setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, .5f);
        batch.draw(shadowbuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), 0, 0);
        batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        batch.end();
        buffer.end();

        batch.begin();

        return buffer.getColorBufferTexture();
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of different blending settings, but none of them work..

**EDIT** Here are the blend settings I'm currently using:

```
    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: I do not see any code where you setup a blend function or even enable blending. The default blend function is SrcRGBA * 1.0 + DestRGB[A] * 0.0, which basically means: "forget about whatever was in the framebuffer before, and replace it!" - since that clearly is not happening here, you are setting up blending somewhere in the code, but are not showing where ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I can't tell if you're being sarcastic or not, but I added my blending setup code

Comment: No, I was being genuine. Anyway, the way things are setup right now, you are telling GL to take SrcRGBA * 0.5 + 0.5 * DestRGBA. This looks pretty normal to me given the parameters you are using. What is your desired result?

Comment: According to the code, this is what to be expected right? What exactly do you want to achieve (desired result)?

Comment: My desired result is for the shadows to appear gray on a white background

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Then you should clear the color buffer to white first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not clear you shadowbuffer to black, clear it to transparent and draw your shadows with black color. Also don't forget to choose right blending function. If you use this method, your parameters will be like

`spritebatch.enableBlending();
spritebatch.setBlendFunction(gl.BLEND_SRC_ALPHA,gl.BLEND_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`